# Verify CRL against its CA

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I am using python, pyopenssl library to verify a CRL against it's CA.

What I have is:

I get the certificate authority:

```
with open(ca_file_path) as ca_file_obj:
     ca = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, ca_file_obj.read())
```

I get the CRL:

```
with open(crl_file_path) as crl_file_obj:
      crl = crypto.load_crl(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, crl_file_obj.read())
```

How can I verify that the CRL belongs to the CA, I know it can be done with openssl, but how to solve it in pure python code, without opening openssl as subprocess ? Any ideeas anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

By using pyopenssl you can do:

```
# Export CRL as a cryptography CRL.
crl_crypto = crl.to_cryptography()

# Get CA Public Key as _RSAPublicKey
ca_pub_key = ca.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key()

# Validate CRL against CA
valid_signature = crl_crypto.is_signature_valid()
```

Take into account that checking the validity of the signature on the CRL is insufficient to know if the CRL should be trusted (See [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.html))

Comment: What else should I verify beside the signature? That the current date is between Last Update and Next Update?